# Circular timer using CAShapelayer

Tags: ios, swift, geometry

Tried to create a circular timer for my app end up with this

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let progressWidth: CGFloat = 10;

    let centerX = CGRectGetMidX(rect)
    let centerY = CGRectGetMidY(rect)
    let center: CGPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect))
    let radius: CGFloat = rect.width / 2


    var circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
    let backgroundCircle = CAShapeLayer()




    backgroundCircle.path = circlePath.CGPath
    backgroundCircle.fillColor = backgroundCircleFillColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(backgroundCircle)

    circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius-progressWidth/2, startAngle: -CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(90)), endAngle:CGFloat(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(currentAngle)), clockwise: true)
    let progressCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    progressCircle.path = circlePath.CGPath
    progressCircle.lineWidth = progressWidth
    progressCircle.strokeColor = progressCircleStrokeColor
    progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)


    let innerCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius-progressWidth, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)

    let innerCircle = CAShapeLayer()
    innerCircle.path = innerCirclePath.CGPath
    innerCircle.fillColor = innerCircleFillColor

    self.layer.addSublayer(innerCircle)
}
```

1. List item
   Here is the output got from my code:

[image: Here is the output got from my code]

Main problems faced in this code are

1. Phone is getting heat while drawing the circle
2. After drawning half of the circle drowning speed decreased

Please help me with an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
import UIKit

class CircularProgressBar: UIView {

    let shapeLayer       = CAShapeLayer()
    let secondShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var circularPath: UIBezierPath?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("Frame: \(self.frame)")
        makeCircle()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        makeCircle()
    }

    func makeCircle(){
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .zero, radius: self.bounds.width / 2, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor//UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        shapeLayer.position = self.center
        shapeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(CATransform3DIdentity, -CGFloat.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }


    func showProgress(percent: Float){
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(percent/100)
    }


}
```

Take a `UIView` in `Storyboard` and add it as a subView. Then you can increase the progress using `showProgress` function.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't add layers in `drawRect:`. Every time your view is drawn, you're adding a layer. That's why it's not surprising that your iPhone is suffering from it and is getting slower and hotter. You should create your layers in `viewDidLoad` or where your view is created, and you shouldn't modify them in `drawRect`. This method is **only** for drawing and nothing else.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can you help me with any other method for drawing the circle

Comment: You may use a shape layer. It will draw it's content automatically by itself, or you draw your paths directly with `UIBezierPath` without layers in `drawRect`.

Comment: if i declare layers globally problem will be solved??

Comment: You should declare them in class scope as properties.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this and worked for me. We need two layers, one for circle and another for progress.

```
private let circularProgressView = UIView()
private let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private let progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
private var circularPath: UIBezierPath?

    private func setupCircularProgressBar() {
    circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: circularProgressView.frame.size.width / 2.0,
                                                   y: circularProgressView.frame.size.height / 2.0),
                                radius: circularProgressView.bounds.width / 2, startAngle: -.pi / 2,
                                endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, clockwise: true)
    
    circleLayer.path = circularPath?.cgPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    circleLayer.lineCap = .round
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 5
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    
    progressLayer.path = circularPath?.cgPath
    progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    progressLayer.lineCap = .round
    progressLayer.lineWidth = 3
    progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    
    circularProgressView.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
    circularProgressView.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
}

private func animateCircularProgress(duration: TimeInterval) {
    let circularProgressAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    circularProgressAnimation.duration = duration
    circularProgressAnimation.toValue = 1
    circularProgressAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
    circularProgressAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
    progressLayer.add(circularProgressAnimation, forKey: "progressAnim")
}
```

usage is very simple you only call animateCircularProgress method with time interval parameter like this with 5 sec duration: `animateCircularProgress(duration: 5)`